# Spark with Scala : Filter RDD by values contained in another list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How would i filter by list.contains() ?
This is my current code, I have a Main class that gets input from command line arguments and according to that input executes the corresponding dispatcher. In this case its a RecommendationDispatcher class that does all it's magic in the constructor - trains a model and generates recommendations for various users that are inputted :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.indexOfAny
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, File, FileWriter}
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import Util.javaHash
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating


import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

class RecommendDispatcher(master:String, inputFile:String, outputFile:String, userList: List[String]) extends java.io.Serializable {

  val format : DecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.#####");
  val file = new File(outputFile)
  val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Movies").setMaster(master)
  val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sparkContext)
  val baseRdd = sparkContext.textFile(inputFile)




  val movieIds = baseRdd.map(line => line.split("\\s+")(1)).distinct().map(id => (javaHash(id), id))

  val userIds = baseRdd.map(line => line.split("\\s+")(3)).distinct()
                                        .filter(x => userList.contains(x))
                                        .map(id => (javaHash(id), id))


  val ratings = baseRdd.map(line => line.split("\\s+"))
    .map(tokens => (tokens(3),tokens(1), tokens(tokens.indexOf("review/score:")+1).toDouble))
      .map( x => Rating(javaHash(x._1),javaHash(x._2),x._3))

  // Build the recommendation model using ALS
  val rank = 10
  val numIterations = 10
  val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)

  val users = userIds.collect()
  var mids = movieIds.collect()

    usrs.foreach(u => {
      bw.write("Recommendations for " + u + ":\n")
      var ranked = List[(Double, Int)]()
      mids.foreach(x => {
        val movieId = x._1
        val prediction = (model.predict(u._1, movieId), movieId)
        ranked = ranked :+ prediction
      })
      //Sort in descending order
      ranked = ranked.sortBy(x => -1 * x._1)
      ranked.foreach(x => bw.write(x._1 + " ; " + x._2 + "\n"))
    })

  bw.close()

}
```

And this exception gets thrown on the ".filter" line :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable

Comment: What is the type of `userList`?

Comment: @ethan Task not serializable exceptions are the result of closure "leakage". The best way to debug these types of errors is using the complete code context. I would suggest that you put your entire code in a Databricks Community Edition notebook and then share the link here. You can sign up at https://accounts.cloud.databricks.com/registration.html#signup/community

Answer (score 3):

I think that a good approach is to convert your `userList` into a [broadcast variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast).

```
val broadcastUserList= sc.broadcast(userList)
val userIds = baseRdd.map(line => line.split("\\s+")(3)).distinct()
                                      .filter(x => broadcastUserList.value.contains(x))
                                      .map(id => (javaHash(id), id))
```

Comment: Seems to have no effect, the result is the same.

Comment: Returns a hash value for the input string value : id

Comment: How does it do it? @Ethan

Comment: The following implementation is not mine :                                           `def javaHash(word: String, seed: Int = 0): Int = {
    var hash = 0

    for (ch <- word.toCharArray)
      hash = 31 * hash + ch.toInt

    hash = hash ^ (hash >> 20) ^ (hash >> 12)
    hash ^ (hash >> 7) ^ (hash >> 4)
  }`

Comment: I have removed javaHash from the map function but i still get the same exception in the filter line.

Comment: then there must be something else in your code... @Ethan

Comment: Broadcast will work only if the broadcastUserList is fairly small. If not, use a join,

Comment: @Ethan, edit your question to include the revised code. This answer should work, so we need to see the code that's still giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing Sim is right about this being closure "leakage" and the sample code you provided is oversimplified.

If your main looks like this:

```
object test
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
  {
    val sc = ...
    val rdd1 = ...
    val userList = ...
    val rdd2 = rdd1.filter { list.contains( _ ) }
  } 
}
```

Then no serialization error occurs. "userList", which is serializable, has no problem to be serialized over to the executors...

The problems begin when you start to model your "big" main into separate classes.

Here is an example of how things might get wrong:

```
class FilterLogic
{
  val userList = List( 1 )  
  def filterRDD( rdd : RDD[ Int ] ) : RDD[ Int ] = 
  {
    rdd.filter { list.contains( _ ) }
  }
}

object Test 
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
  {
    val sc = ...
    val rdd1 = ...
    val rdd2 = new FilterLogic().filterRDD( rdd1 )// This will result in a serialization error!!!
  }
}
```

Now that userList is a value of the Logic class, when it needs to be serialized over to the executors it demands the entire wrapping Logic class to be serialized as well ( Why? because in Scala userList is actually a getter in the Logic class ).

A few ways to solve this problem:

1) userList can be created inside the filterRDD function, then it is not a val of Logic ( works but limits code sharing/modeling )

1.1) Similar idea is using a temp val inside the the filterRDD function  like so:

```
val list_ = list ; rdd.filter { list_.contains( _ ) }
```

works but so ugly it's almost painful...

2) Logic class can be made Serializable ( sometimes it might not be possible to make it serializable though )

Lastly, using a broadcast might have ( or not have ) its benefits but it is not related to the serialization error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to serialize the RecommendDispatcher class but have still gotten the same Exception. So i decided to put the code in the Main class instead and that solved my problem.